# How do I destructuring-match syntax::ptr::P?

Tags: rust

I have a function which tries to match an `syntax::ast::ExprBinary(syntax::ast::BinOp, syntax::ptr::P<ast::Expr>, syntax::ptr::P<syntax::ast::Expr>)`, but I cannot find the right syntax to match the `P` so I get the contained expression out of it. I see that I can use `Deref` to get at the `Expr`, but this is cumbersome.

Is there a way to get rid of the `P` within the `match` (or `if let`) clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to pattern match through a `P`: [the field is private](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d4cedea80a70d61931e4442dde90bd136a60deeb/src/libsyntax/ptr.rs#L48) and we don't have generalised pointer pattern matching (yet).

The only ways to get at the contained data are `Deref` (for a `&`), and the methods `and_then` and `map` (for by-value).